# PHP mail adding background color does not color in other div tags inside

Tags: php, email

[image: 1]

```
    $email = "***EMAIL RECIEVED***";
    include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setFrom('***EMAIL FROM***');
    $mail->addAddress($email);
    $mail->Subject = "MyWhiteCard Coupon Claimed!";
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body =
      "<body style='background-color: #fbedde; width:800px; text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>
              <img src='cid:logo' width='40%' style='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top: 20px;'>
              <h1 style='color: #00a6a6; letter-spacing: 2px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-family: 'brandon_black';'>COUPON CLAIMED</h1>

           <div style='padding-top:30px; width: 400px;float:left;'>
              <img src='cid:coupon' width='85%' style='padding-left: auto; padding-right: auto; margin-bottom: 65px; border-radius: 2% !important; box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);'>
           </div>

            <div style='padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 33px; width: 400px; float: left; text-align: left; color: #00a6a6'>
              <h3 style='font-weight: bold;'>Claimed By:</h3>
              <h2 style='letter-spacing: 1px; font-family: 'brandon_black';'>$usr_fname $usr_lname</h2>
              <h3 style='font-weight: bold;'>$usr_contact</h3>
              <h3 style='font-weight: bold;'>$usr_member</h3><br>
              <h3>Please proceed to</h3>
              <a href='https://www.mywhitecard.ph/cms' style='color: #00a6a6; text-decoration: underline;'>https://www.mywhitecard.ph/cms</a>
              <h3>for scheduling of member.</h3>
           </div>
        </body>";

    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage(dirname(__FILE__) . '***IMG LINK***','logo');
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage(dirname(__FILE__) . '***IMG LINK***','coupon');
    $mail->send();
```

First of all I had to add all css in style="" because I am sending this via PHP email. My issue is I have a body tag with a background color, but my two other div tags inside does not color them. How come this is happening?

Comment: CSS and HTML are very poorly supported by many mail clients. Take a look [here](https://www.email-standards.org/index.html).

Comment: Basically code your emails in html3 with some basic css. Even then not all html3 elements will work consistently. Use images as much as possible, they will retain info more in correct position, regardless wether viewed on mobile or desktop email client

Answer (score 0):

You have both of those elements floated, so they do not affect the height of their ancestors any more.

In a normal HTML page that would not lead to the effect you are seeing, because there is some built-in “magic” that lets the `body` element background grow to the full viewport height, if the `html` element does not have any background color of its own, but in the context where your mail gets displayed later on, that might be different.

So apply a *clearfix* to get body to contain those two elements.